# After Updating the SDK API22 Not Showing App Icon, Action Bar Theme Color Changed as Default

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

I updated my SDK **API 20** to **API 22** in Eclipse.

After Updating My Sdk i Imported My Project from Other Workspace

Problem:

1. Actionbar **App icon Not Showing** in My Application.
2. I Already set theme Color in Themes.xml thats not Showing. it Changed as **Default Black Colour**.

Its Changed full structure of my App. Before Updating it works fine.

Please anyone Help me to Solve this.

manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 </application>
```

Themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->

        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Divider</item>
    </style>

<!-- for Tab divider -->
<style name="Divider" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item> //or use your transparent drawable image
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
</style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/easy</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/easy</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabs" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">

        <!-- This is a Black text color when selected and a WHITE color otherwise -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_tab_text</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

To show icon use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_your_icon);
```

in your activity `onCreate()`

And for color add:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/your_color</item>
```

to "CustomActionBarTheme" (not to "MyActionBar"!)

And your theme should look like:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/your_color</item><!--put your color here-->
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->

        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Divider</item>
    </style>
```

And the other stuff in your theme.xml stays unchanged

Comment: we Can,t Add a icon in single place ,to Show in All Pages ?

Comment: you have to do it in every activity, but not in fragment. The fragments show icon of their activity

Comment: ok. iam trying ,can you suggest  me Full theme.xml Code for Changing Color in Actionbar